# Misconfigured .NET + Angular SPA

Tags: angular, .net-core

I have some wrong configuration in my app I am not able to fix. It is a .NET 8 + Angular 17 app.

This is my current configuration related to SPA (.NET, angular below)

```
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddSpaStaticFiles(config =>
{
    config.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
});

var app = builder.Build();

app.UseDefaultFiles();
app.UseSpaStaticFiles();

app.UseSpa(config =>
{
    config.Options.SourcePath = "ClientApp";

    if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
    {
        config.UseAngularCliServer(npmScript: "start");
    }
});

app.Run();
```

```
------------------- package.json
"scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "dev:ssr": "ng run Institut:serve-ssr",
    "serve:ssr": "node dist/server/main.js",
    "build:ssr": "ng build && ng run Institut:server",
    "build:ssr:prod": "ng build --configuration=production && ng run Institut:server:production",
    "prerender": "ng run Institut:prerender",
},

------------------- angular.json
"serve": {
    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
    "options": {
        "browserTarget": "Institut:build",
        "proxyConfig": "src/proxy.conf.json"
    },
    "configurations": {
        "production": {
            "browserTarget": "Institut:build:production"
        },
        "development": {
            "browserTarget": "Institut:build:development"
        }
    },
    "defaultConfiguration": "development"
},

------------------- proxy.conf.json
{
  "/api": {
    "target": "https://localhost:44386",
    "secure": false
  }
}
```

The issue I have is that when I launch the api with the new configuration, the client is not able to call my API and gives this error in Rider's console :

```
404.20 error: Response sent to https://localhost:44386/api/api/api/.../ClientCategory/GetAll
```

When I remove app.UseSpa, the API works fine via postman. Indeed, not the angular app. The weird thing is the call url which has duplicated `/api` blocks, and I did not find why at the moment.

I have no idea what can I test to fix this issue. If this can help, the objective is to use an Angular app with SSR enabled. For now I am just trying to make the app work as it did before (using standard template for .NET + Angular, but which wasn't SSR-enabled).

Thanks a lot